# Popover TableView is not showing a checkmark on selection (iOS7.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, checkmark

I have a button which when clicked shows a popover with a table view which is showing some list of data.

On selection of a table view row, I want to show a check mark on the right hand side of the cell, but the code is not working. Can someone help me to diagnose this?

The same code is working well if I use only a normal tableview instead of popover table view.

Currently i am using XCode 5.1.1 , iOS7.1 , iPad Simulator.

```
//@property (assign,nonatomic)int selectedIndex;
//@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *listArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.    
    return [self.listArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    // Configure cell now
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    return cell;

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}

//For Button Action Method

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

    TableViewController *tableViewController = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:tableViewController];

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:button permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: what is ' selectedIndex ' , please check the that condition is satisfying.

Comment: selectedIndex is a int variable, it is working fine in case of normal table view but failing in case of popover tableview.

Comment: is that condition  satisfied ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the code. Your popoverview is not big enough to cover the right boundary of tableview. Make the frame of your tableview proper and you will find the check mark.

Comment: No, it is not working. Please check my edited button action method.